# Spring form cannot match collection. ResponseStatusExceptionResolver ....typeMismatch

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-form

I have following class:

```
public class TerminalAdmin {

    ....
    private Set<AdminRole> adminRoles;
}
```

and this:

```
public class AdminRole {
    ....
    private Long adminId;       
    private String role;
}
```

controller:

```
model.addAttribute("adminRoles",terminalAdminService.findAllAdminRoles());
model.addAttribute("newAdmin",new TerminalAdmin());
return "admin/adminUsers";
```

jsp:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="newAdmin" action="/admin/addNewAdmin">            
    <div class="line">
            <label for="">role</label>
            <form:checkboxes items="${adminRoles}" path="adminRoles"/>
            <div class="clear"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="line">
            <input class="btn" type="submit" value="save"/>
            <div class="clear"></div>
     </div>
</form:form>
```

When I submit foem I see message:

```
HTTP Status 400 -

type Status report

message

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

Spring log:

```
Field error in object 'terminalAdmin' on field 'adminRoles': rejected value [ROLE_IMAGE_MODERATOR]; codes [typeMismatch.terminalAdmin.adminRoles,typeMismatch.adminRoles,typeMismatch.java.util.Set,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [terminalAdmin.adminRoles,adminRoles]; arguments []; default message [adminRoles]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Set' for property 'adminRoles'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.terminal.domain.admin.AdminRole] for property 'adminRoles[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.terminal.controller.admin.AdminController.adminUsers(com.terminal.domain.admin.TerminalAdmin)]: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'terminalAdmin' on field 'adminRoles': rejected value [ROLE_IMAGE_MODERATOR]; codes [typeMismatch.terminalAdmin.adminRoles,typeMismatch.adminRoles,typeMismatch.java.util.Set,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [terminalAdmin.adminRoles,adminRoles]; arguments []; default message [adminRoles]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Set' for property 'adminRoles'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.terminal.domain.admin.AdminRole] for property 'adminRoles[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.terminal.controller.admin.AdminController.adminUsers(com.terminal.domain.admin.TerminalAdmin)]: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'terminalAdmin' on field 'adminRoles': rejected value [ROLE_IMAGE_MODERATOR]; codes [typeMismatch.terminalAdmin.adminRoles,typeMismatch.adminRoles,typeMismatch.java.util.Set,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [terminalAdmin.adminRoles,adminRoles]; arguments []; default message [adminRoles]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Set' for property 'adminRoles'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.terminal.domain.admin.AdminRole] for property 'adminRoles[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

How to rewrite code to avoid following error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem using following code:

```
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(AdminRole.class,  new PropertyEditorSupport() {
            public void setAsText(String name) {
                AdminRole adminRole = terminalAdminService.findRoleByName(name);
                setValue(adminRole);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you got is clear: You have to setup a property editor or conversion service for letting the binder know how to create an AdminRole object out of a String (which is what actually you have for each checkbox).

If you inspect your jsp page source code, you'll probably see that the checkbox is represented as an array of strings (in fact you'll see the same field name as many times as the checkbox entries size). When you post the form, the binder tries to crete a collection of AdminRoles but the best it can do if no proper conversion strategy is present, is to create a collection of Strings out of the array.